# I can not create new Routes in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I was developing a Full-Stack Laravel project using livewire and tailwind CSS in the front, everything was working just fine, I even did 5 commits on GitHub on this project. The problem is I came back to continue developing the project, and when I create new routes, Laravel returns 404 PAGE NOT FOUND, I even tried to test a very simple route, and it did not work too(404 page not found)

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'hi';
});
```

Any solution to this weird problem?

Comment: Tried caching the routes using `php artisan route:cache` or clearing the cache using  `php artisan route:clear` ?

Comment: The is a little sketchy on the details regarding you server setup, domain mapping, etc.

Comment: Tried php artisan route:cahce and route:clear, still does not work

Comment: Run `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Did you clone the project again?

Comment: Did you maybe create a new file to put your routes in? The route should be registrered into the `RouteServiceProvider.php`. Is the project on the server(?) really updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a chaching problem.

Try clear your cache by running

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear
```

You can also check all registered routes by running
`php artisan route:list`.

If thats not working it could also be a problem with the browsers internal cache. Had something like this before with Firefox.

Try using curl to access the endpoint

`curl http://localhost:8080/test`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after moving the project to a different machine. The cause was that the bootstrap/cache directory was not writable to the web server / php process.